# Could not get BatchedBridge on React-Native ios?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I create a raw react-native project but when i ran the project on IOS it gave me the following error the "Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packages correctly".

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
react-native run-android
react-native start --reset-cache
```

Answer (score 0):

On React Native 0.70, adding the following line in use_react_native!(...) Podfile fixed the error:

```
 :flipper_configuration => FlipperConfiguration.enabled,
```

But don't know why.